# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar datos en listas de java diferentes para después concatenarlos y mostrarlos?

Tags: java, lista, netbeans

Hola apenas me estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación y nos pusieron una actividad que no encuentro mucha información, necesito pedir 5 datos al usuario en NetBeans (nombre) (edad) (NIT) (Lugar de nacimiento) (Sueldo) y esto lo tengo que hacer con varios usuarios entonces necesito guardar los datos en unas listas y después con un índex que el usuario elija si quiere ver algún perfil en especifico o las quiere ver todas, les agradezco :,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con java 8 lo puedes hacer a traves de Streams asi

```
List<Usuario> listaUsuariosFiltrada=listaUsuarios
   .filter(usuario-> //aqui colocas un predicado como este
             usuario.getNombre().equals("algun nombre"))
    `introducir el código aquí`.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me base en lo que me enviaste y me sirvió eres el mejor :,)